# Facebook - "Cannot query users by their username" solution

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.2

I am developing an android app. I was using a HttpURLConnection to get profile pictures of facebook users. The URL looks like this:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=username1,username2,username3&fields=picture&type=square
```

But now, since v2.2 doesn't let me to get profile pictures of users who are not using my facebook app, it throws an error:

> {    "error": {
> "message": "(#803) Cannot query users by their username (username1)",
> "type": "OAuthException",
> "code": 803    } }

I am not interested in using "Facebook SDK for Android". Let's say I use a pop-up webview to authorize my facebook app. What url would let me do the same thing? Is there a simple solution like this:

graph.facebook.com/?app=**APP-ID**&ids=username1,username2&fields=picture

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Since v2.0 of the API, you are not supposed to use usernames at all - and that´s why you can´t query users by their username anymore. The only way to get access to data of a user is by authorizing that user and using the `/me` endpoint.

Main rule: Forget about users who did not authorize your App, you are not supposed to get any data of those for privacy reason.

Comment: they scrape the profile, which is not allowed on facebook. don´t do that.