# Get the Facebook User ID from a random profile URL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

There are several solutions proposed, but as is stated here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/26839926/1893249 ) , it seems to be impossible.

In the FB Graph API explorer( https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer ), "/v2.4/cnn" returns the following, which is promising,

```
{
  "name": "CNN",
  "id": "5550296508"
}
```

until you put in "/v2.4/priscilla" and it returns:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#803) Cannot query users by their username (priscilla)",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 803
  }
}
```

Likewise, this approach looks promising "/v2.4/?ids=http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/"
until you put in "/v2.4/?ids=https://www.facebook.com/priscilla"
and it just returns the not-so-helpful:

```
{
  "https://www.facebook.com/priscilla": {
    "id": "https://www.facebook.com/priscilla"
  }
}
```

But if it's impossible, than how is it done here?
http://findmyfbid.com/ with the URL,
https://www.facebook.com/priscilla

Comment: _“than how is it done here?”_ – by them scraping the FB page, for which they probably don’t have permission to do so.

Comment: More information here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30886783/405525

Answer (score 2):

Scrapping the Facebook page Does the trick, but I'doubt if it's legal

```
curl -v https://www.facebook.com/USERNAME 2>&1 | 
grep -o 'userID.*]' | head -n1 | cut -c 10-24
```

Comment: Why would you post an answer that you know violates Facebook TOS.