# What actually get_Object() takes as a parameter in Fabook SDK?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to send friend name as a user in `get_object()`in below code for getting his public posts. But I am getting error

> raise GraphAPIError(result)
>   facebook.GraphAPIError: (#803) Cannot query users by their username (tayyab.rasheed.545)

```
user = 'tayyab.rasheed.545' #is giving error
#user = 'BillGates'         #is working fine.
# user = 'me'               #is working fine.

graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token)
profile = graph.get_object(user)
posts = graph.get_connections(profile['id'], 'posts')
```

Why is the error? I think I am doing something wrong. `BillGates` and `me` is working fine then why not `tayyab.rasheed.545` Profile of friend is 'https://www.facebook.com/tayyab.rasheed.545'

Comment: btw, this has been answered already, please use the search function first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30886468/facebook-cannot-query-users-by-their-username-solution

Answer (score 1):

> Why is the error?

Because Facebook removed the username field from the API with v2.0, and as the error message says, you can not query user profiles by their username any more.

> `BillGates` and `me` is working fine then why not `tayyab.rasheed.545

`BillGates` simply is a Facebook *Page*, and not a user profile.

(And `me` has nothing to do with the username in the first place.)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to get public posts of any user. Even for you own public posts, you need to authorized yourself with the `user_posts` permission.

Edit: Please don´t change your question, especially when there is an answer already. CBroes answer is correct. You are not supposed to get any data of users who did not authorized your App anyway.

Comment: @luschn, I think this answer was meant for a different question …?

Comment: oh...that is weird...i guess it was a caching issue, thanx!

Comment: no, it was actually meant for this question, but he completely edited it, look at the history...not cool :/

Comment: Ah yeah, right, saw that “original” question before already and your answer to it, so I assumed this was another, individual question, and the answer got posted to that one accidentally.

Comment: @luschn Really sorry. I thought I should not increase the database by one question by adding one new question. That is why, I edited that to a new one.

Comment: my answer did not make any sense anymore. new topic, new question. but you should really use the search function next time before asking, that error comes up quite often and it´s a well known one. if you really don´t want to "increase the database", that would be the way to go (google, SO search) ;)